# How does cancer radiotherapy target only cancer cells?

Tags: cancer, radiology, radiation

I read about cancer treatment where the patient would be given radiation to kill cancer cells. How do they make sure that it affects mostly the cancer cells?
Moreover how do they manage it so that it kills cancer cells but does not causes more cancer by radiation poisoning.

Comment: Very careful aim.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.cancer.gov/about-cancer/treatment/types/radiation-therapy/radiation-fact-sheet
The quick answer is the healthy cells do get radiations (you may read more info on the above link), but they came up with a clever idea on how to minimalize the radiation absorbed by healthy cells but at the same time give a lot of radiation to the cancer cells. Look at this video from 1:44. https://youtu.be/_moypMx05Fw
Simply enough, they used computer to analyze 3D picture of your body, then "shoots" the cancer cells from different angles so that the healthy cells get minimum damage. This doesn't relate to the question but maybe you want to know that cancer cells are weaker than normal cells because they are too busy growing and less organized that normal cells which makes them harder to recover from the radiation. That makes things a lot easier. This is link to the proof. http://www.breastcancer.org/treatment/radiation/how_works

Comment: It is for this reason that some tumours can't be treated with radiation. It's not that they wouldn't respond, it's that there isn't an angle that lets them aim at the tumour without getting some vital organ damaged as well.

Comment: It doesn't really address why malignant cells are more susceptible to radiation vs normal cells.  If your link contains that information you should abstract that out as links are subject to link rot.

Comment: @Kate Gregory although it is true that some conditions of tumors that can't be targetted without getting vital organs damaged, there are a lot of cases that it works. OP asks how it works and it is shown in the answer.

Comment: @Graham Chiu whether cancer cells are more susceptible to radiation or not, the logic of the above procedure remains true. The fact that cancer cells so busy on dividing and less organized that makes them harder to recover only ease the process and we take that for granted. OP asked how radiotherapy target the cancer cells and its not in the scope of the question to write about how weak cancer cells are.

Comment: Because your answer is a link answer

Comment: Do you see or not see the wall of text on my answer?

Comment: @KennethKho not arguing, just commenting. I don't have a problem with your answer, just adding a "by the way" to it

Comment: @KennethKho your wall of text adds very little to explain what is happening.  There is no mechanism being explained.

Comment: The second answer is the same as mine , with helpful net references.

Comment: @blacksmith37 References aren't merely helpful; they're required here. If you edited your answer and added a link or two to credible references that support your assertions of fact, your answer would probably be upvoted.

Comment: The references are about 10 doctors and technicians at MDAnderson that I talked with during a couple years of chemo, radiation and surgery .  I don't remember which said what partly because the chemo affects your memory.